# Are there better estimates on Taylor remainders than Taylor's formula gives?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

Given an $n+1$ times differentiable $f$, we have $f(x) = T_n(x) + R_n(x)$ with $$T_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$$

and $$R_n(x) = f^{(n+1)}(z)\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

for some $z$ between $x$ and $a$. We can then take $M_n(x)$ to be the supremum of $|f^{(n+1)}(t)|$ on the interval between $a$ and $x$ to get the estimate

$$|R_n(x)| \leq M_n(x)\frac{|x-a|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.$$

In some cases we can use this to prove that for a given $x$, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} R_n(x) = 0$, which gives convergence to $f(x)$ of the Taylor series for $f$ evaluated at $x$.

But there are cases where $x$ is in the interval of convergence for the Taylor series for $f$, but where $M_n(x)$ overshoots $|f^{(n+1)}(z)|$ badly, and grows fast enough that $M_n(x)\frac{|x-a|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ does not converge, and thus this method could not be used to show convergence of the Taylor series for $f$ to $f$.

A specific example is the Maclaurin series $1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots$ for $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ evaluated at $0<x<1$. One can show that $M_n(x) = \frac{(n+1)!}{(1-x)^{n+2}}$, and hence the standard estimate gives
$$|R_n(x)| \leq M_n(x)\frac{|x-a|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^{n+2}}.$$ The right hand side does not go to $0$ if $\tfrac{1}{2}\leq x < 1$, even though the series is geometric and hence clearly converges to $f$ for all of these $x$ values. How would one show that the Taylor series converged to $f$ here if we didn't happen to have a nice geometric series?

Are there general stronger estimates for the remainder $|R_n(x)|$ than the one given above?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on $X=(x_0-a,x_0+a)$ for some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}, a>0$. Let $f$ be $n+1$ times continuosly differentiable on X. Then Taylor remainder can be written in this way:
$R_n(x)=\frac{1}{n!} \int\limits_{x_0}^{x} (x-t)^n f^{(n+1)}(t)dt$ for all $x\in X$.
That form is called an integral form of Taylor remainder. It is used to prove that functions $(1+x)^c$ are real analytic on $(-1,1)$.